# Dojo 1.8 Filtering Select auto suggest feature giving symbols in IE 8

Tags: javascript, dojox.grid, dojo

Following is the behaviour of DOJO 1.8 auto suggest in IE 8

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html

It shows special characters between the text in IE8.Check the above link to see the exact behaviour.

I guess the issue is with the latest DOJO relaese ,please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FilteringSelect uses a unicode annotation character to highlight the matching part of the suggestions. I see the same thing here, so I guess IE has a problem rendering them and it slipped past the dojo tests.

No idea how to fix it, but as a temporary measure, you can set the FilteringSelect's "highlightMatch" to "none".

Edit: It seems to be a known bug related to the build tool/shrinksafe: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15969